# Event Receiver on SharePoint-hosted Apps

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-enterprise, event-receivers, 2013

Is it possible to create event receiver or workflow on SharePoint-hosted apps in SharePoint 2013? I have not much knowledge about SharePoint apps. If yes then how to create it...

Can we use Remote Event Receiver in SharePoint hosted apps?

Comment: have you try same way which developed in SP2010?

Comment: Hi @Jigs. Thanks for your reply. But How can i deploy event receiver on my custom SharePoint-hosted app? What can i add siteURL in Project Properties? Can i use List which is added in SharePoint-hosted apps?

Comment: yes.you can.if you used custom list template than associate template ID on your Event Receiver's Element file like `<Receivers ListTemplateId="TemplateID">`

Comment: @Jigs I have created one task list in SharePoint-hosted apps. So TemplateID is that <Receivers ListTemplateId="171">.. But Event is not fired on Item Added in Tasks list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you attempt to add a Remote Event Receiver to a SharePoint-hosted app project, Visual Studio will add a new web application project to the solution that includes a remote event receiver WCF service. Because a remote event receiver relies on a WCF endpoint to "remotely" handle the events being raised from SharePoint, and this WCF endpoint contains server-side code, by definition it cannot run in a SharePoint-hosted app. For more information, see [this remote event receiver how-to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/jj220043.aspx) on MSDN.

You **can**, however, create and deploy simple workflows within SharePoint-hosted apps. You can read more about workflow-powered apps for SharePoint [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj191508.aspx). In general, you should only use workflow in a SharePoint-hosted app when the workflow is integral to the app for SharePoint itself, as the workflow will only be operating on lists within the app web. *(Note that in order to successfully build my SharePoint-hosted app project using the [Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2012 - Preview 2](http://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/WebPI.ashx?command=GetInstallerRedirect&appid=OfficeToolsForVS2012GA), I had to add references to System.Web 4.0.0.0 and System.Drawing 4.0.0.0.)*

Alternatively, look for references to System.Web in the .xaml and .csproj files and remove. This option was found by doing a comparison between the generated files in Visual Studio and what was provided in a working solution on GitHub (https://github.com/OfficeDev/SharePoint_SP-hosted_Add-Ins_Tutorials) provided for the MSDN tutorial series about SharePoint-hosted Add-ins.

Comment: Hello @Danny Jessee, I have tried workflow on SharePoint hosted apps, but it gives error.. So Workflow manager tool is required for creating workflow on SharePoint hosted apps?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? I do have Workflow Manager 1.0 installed and configured in my environment per this article: http://blog.cloudshare.com/2013/01/15/how-to-install-and-configure-workflow-infrastructure-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: Ya @Danny Jessee, In workflow manager installation process,it download some files and i have no permission to access internet... But thanks for your reply and i will try.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, look for references to System.Web in the .xaml and .csproj files and remove. This option was found by doing a comparison between the generated files in Visual Studio and what was provided in a working solution on GitHub (https://github.com/OfficeDev/SharePoint_SP-hosted_Add-Ins_Tutorials) provided for the MSDN tutorial series about SharePoint-hosted Add-ins.

(Sorry about the edit, Danny. Still learning StackExchange.)